# Gene Sequencing

Tags: genetics, dna-sequencing

The human genome project took an effort of around 15 years, billions of dollars and thousands of scientists working together.
So how is that the genetic sequencing of covid variants could be done at such a faster rate?

Comment: Welcome Tarique. We are expected to show the results of our own investigations into a subject here, you can [edit] to tell us what your searches found and where the sticking points are. You should also take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to the ways of any site you post on and see our [homework-question policy](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266/homework-policy-for-faq). Enjoy the Stackexchange network. (The human genome is over 130,000 times bigger and then there's Moore's law too).

Comment: Practice, practice, practice. The technology required is now in place.

Answer (score 1):

The sequencing techniques have evolved, notably with spread of [the next generation sequencing (NGS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_parallel_sequencing) and more recently nanopore. [Sanger sequencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanger_sequencing) used in the first human genome project is a rather slow technique, although still widely used (especially in clinical setting).